# Como deletar dados de várias tabelas ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: php, pdo

Pessoal por segurança eu resolvi usar Transaction, eu espero que funcione assim:

Conclui apenas se todas as querys rodarem.

Você sugerem algo melhor?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['deletar']) && $_GET['deletar'] == 'sim'):
    $lojista = (int)$_GET['lojista'];
    BD::conn()->beginTransaction();
    $deletar_lojista = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `loja_lojistas` WHERE `id` = :id");
    $deletar_lojista->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_lojista->execute();
    if(!$deletar_lojista){
        BD::conn()->rollBack();
    }

    $deletar_loja = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `admin_lojas` WHERE `id_loja` = :id");
    $deletar_loja->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_loja->execute();
    if(!$deletar_loja){
        BD::conn()->rollBack();
    }

    // Apaga todas as fotos de produtos que o Lojista cadastrou
    $deletar_fotos_produtos = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT `imagem` FROM `loja_produtos` WHERE `id_loja` = :id");
    $deletar_fotos_produtos->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_fotos_produtos->execute();
    $foto = $deletar_fotos_produtos->fetchObject();
    unlink('../../../www/produtos/'.$foto->imagem);

    $deletar_produtos = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `loja_produtos` WHERE `id_loja` = :id");
    $deletar_produtos->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_produtos->execute();
    if(!$deletar_produtos){
        BD::conn()->rollBack();
    }

    $deletar_produtos_pedidos = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `loja_produtos_pedidos` WHERE `id_loja` = :id");
    $deletar_produtos_pedidos->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_produtos_pedidos->execute();
    if(!$deletar_produtos_pedidos){
        BD::conn()->rollBack();
    }

    $deletar_pedidos = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `loja_pedidos` WHERE `id_loja` = :id");
    $deletar_pedidos->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_pedidos->execute();
    if(!$deletar_pedidos){
        BD::conn()->rollBack();
    }

    $deletar_categorias = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `loja_categorias` WHERE `id_loja` = :id");
    $deletar_categorias->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_categorias->execute();
    if(!$deletar_categorias){
        BD::conn()->rollBack();
    }

    $deletar_subcategorias = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `loja_subcategorias` WHERE `id_loja` = :id");
    $deletar_subcategorias->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_subcategorias->execute();
    if(!$deletar_subcategorias){
        BD::conn()->rollBack();
    }

    $deletar_pagamentos = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `admin_pagamentos` WHERE `id_lojista` = :id");
    $deletar_pagamentos->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_pagamentos->execute();
    if(!$deletar_pagamentos){
        BD::conn()->rollBack();
    }

    $deletar_vencimentos = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `admin_vencimentos` WHERE `id_lojista` = :id");
    $deletar_vencimentos->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_vencimentos->execute();
    if(!$deletar_vencimentos){
        BD::conn()->rollBack();
    }

    BD::conn()->commit();
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            $.alert({
                theme: 'black',
                title: 'Deletado com sucesso!',
                content: '',
                icon: '',
                confirmButton: 'OK',
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
                animation: 'scale',
                animationClose: 'top',
                opacity: 0.5,
            });
        </script>";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Sim, um framework e/ou um ORM rsrsrs.

Comment: Aí a transação falha, fica tudo no DB, mas as fotos foram deletadas do HD de qualquer jeito. Melhor seria se ao final, confirmado o sucesso da transação, você deletasse as fotos. O que pode fazer aí, se muda o banco, é criar uma função DeletarDoDb( $conexao, $tabela, $id ) pra facilitar a vida. Ou fazer em um foreach, passando a lista de tabelas como array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize `exceptions` em conjunto. É fácil verificar que está utilizando PDO. Uma vez usando exceptions, não precisa validar retornos do método `PDOStatement::execute()`, apenas seguir adiante.

Primeiro deve ativar o lançamento de exceções:

```
//Ativa o lançamento de exceptions para erros
BD::conn()->->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE , PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Após, o script de exclusão.

```
try {        
    BD::conn()->beginTransaction();

    $deletar_lojista = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `loja_lojistas` WHERE `id` = :id");
    $deletar_lojista->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_lojista->execute();

    $deletar_loja = BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM `admin_lojas` WHERE `id_loja` = :id");
    $deletar_loja->bindValue(':id', $lojista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $deletar_loja->execute();

    /** 
        todas as suas demais transações 
    **/

    BD::conn()->commit();

    /** 
        passe a exclusão física dos arquivos para o final do script, 
        após o commit das transações
    **/    

    // Apaga todas as fotos de produtos que o Lojista cadastrou
    //A foto deve ter sido consultada antes do commit, após, o registro não existe mais no SGBD
    unlink('../../../www/produtos/'.$foto->imagem);
} catch (PDOException $exception) {
    BD::conn()->rollback();

    printf('Não foi possível realizar a operação: %s' , $exception);
}
```

Se o comando ocorrer com sucesso, o script continuará sendo executado, caso houver uma falha, será lançada uma `PDOException`. Entenda como falha, quando não é possível excluir um registro existente (uma dependência, falha de conexão, privilégios).

Utilizando retornos, você pode ter um resultado diferente, pois uma exclusão com uma clausula `WHERE` de um registro que não existe, pode retornar `false`. Entretanto, não foi a execução do `DELETE` ou o registro que não foi excluído e sim o registro que não existe conforme a clausula.

O mesmo pode ocorrer com um `UPDATE`. Em `prepared statements`, se você realizar um `UPDATE` para um registro, e atualizar com os mesmos valores já existentes, esse `UPDATE` não será realizado, pois não haverá mudança no registro e nem linhas afetadas. Entretanto, isso pode mudar de SGBD para SGBD, por isso é importante ficar atento entre retornos, erros e exceções. Sempre sendo recomendado o uso de exceções.

Comment: E se por um acaso ao deletar o lojista, não existir nenhum pagamento ainda feito por ele? vai dar exception la em admin_pagamentos e não concluir nenhum daqueles outros processos?

Comment: @JonathanSilva Não. O fato da instrução `DELETE` não encontrar resultados para excluir não é um erro. A instrução irá ser executada normalmente, com 0 (zero) linhas afetadas e passará para a próxima instrução. Uma exceção será lançada somente se ocorrer um erro, como um registro dependente, falta de privilégios, etc.

Comment: no caso ao deletar o lojista, como não tinha produtos e muito menos a foto do produto, deu erro mas deletou o resto. Não tem problema? http://imgur.com/a/mxHJM

Comment: a princípio, se não lançou exception, o erro não tem relação. Qual foi o erro?

Comment: mandei o link do print acima, a linha do erro é onde tem unlink('../../../www/produtos/'.$foto->imagem);

Comment: A variável que você está usando para excluir o arquivo não é um objeto. Não é um erro da transação.